# Error con las actualizaciones

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas amigos del foros, esperando que todos se encuentre muy bien, realize una actualización de android.studio y a su vez en las dependencias, las cuales me arrojaron varios errores, pero hay cinco que no he podido sacarlos, primero les presento el buid.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.prueba"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.7'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0'
}
```

posteriormente les presento el error en el primer fragment llamado ingreso en el cual se realizo el siguiente código para dejar deshabilitado el botón de atrás, para que el usuario solo use los fragmento y el botón salir, este es el código:

```
requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Para salir debe presionar el botón salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

posteriormente los errores que presenta son el "Cannot resolve method 'addCallback(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner, anonymous OnBackPressedCallback)" y el otro error es en "Cannot resolve symbol 'OnBackPressedCallback'", he tratado incluso de volver a las versiones más antiguas y sigue con el mismo error en las depedencias, el otro error, que no puedo sacar es el siguiente:

```
txtfono4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (txtfono4 != null){
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
                builder.setMessage("¿Este siniestro posee Tercero?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        txttercero.requestFocus();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        llenarSpinner3();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setTitle("Gestión");
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

el error en si es en el alert.show es el siguiente "Cannot resolve method 'show' in 'AlertDialog'", las librerías se encuentra bien, como se presenta a continuación:

```
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

si necesitan algo más me lo hacen saber, para solucionar este problema y desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Pero ¿los gradle se sincronizan bien? Si es así, entonces puedes intentar desde el menú `File` con la opción `Invalidate Caches`. Marca las tres casillas y pulsa `Invalidate and Restart`. Espera que Android Studio se reinicie y no toques nada hasta que no cargue de nuevo todos los archivos.

Comment: @A.Cedano te cuento que los hice varias veces ese proceso y nada, sigue con el mismo problema, así que fue lo que hice volví del 34 al 33 y ningún problema fue lo mejor que pude hacer ya que llevaba varios día sen esto, además la pagina de android no menciona las librerías que son compatibles con la 34 que se encuentra disponible, de todas maneras muchas gracias

Comment: Entiendo. Debe ser algún problema de compatibilidad de alguna librería o algo así. De todos modos tendrás que resolver esto no muy tarde. Ya que Play Store va restringiendo subir aplicaciones con un target inferior, ahora está en la versión 33 como mínimo. Revisando los log de error podrás ver cuál es la incompatibilidad, de librería o de código y corregirla.

Comment: @A.Cedano te cuento que el problema era implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0', la cual la cambie por la implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0', y se soluciono ya que baje anteriormente había bajado el SDK manager y 34 y para no volver a atrás tuve que hacerlo esta manera, pero se soluciono